# Percentagem em SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Tenho o seguinte código de consulta:

```
SELECT
    AC.DT_AGENDA               AS DATA,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA        AS EMPRESA,
    AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS CD_UNID_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO, 
    COUNT(IAC.NM_PACIENTE)     AS TOTAL_MARCADOS,
    COUNT(IAC.CD_ATENDIMENTO)  AS ATENDIDOS

FROM AGENDA_CENTRAL AC
    INNER JOIN IT_AGENDA_CENTRAL   IAC   ON AC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL      = IAC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL
    INNER JOIN UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO UA    ON UA.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO = AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO
    INNER JOIN MULTI_EMPRESAS      ME    ON ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA       = AC.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA
WHERE IAC.NM_PACIENTE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA,
    AC.DT_AGENDA
```

Quero saber baseado no `count`, quantos por cento representa o `ATENDIDOS` sobre `count TOTAL_MARCADOS`.

Ou seja,

10 Marcados
5 Atendidos
50% foram atendidos do total marcado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente,

```
SELECT
    AC.DT_AGENDA               AS DATA,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA        AS EMPRESA,
    AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS CD_UNID_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO  AS UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO, 
    COUNT(IAC.NM_PACIENTE)     AS TOTAL_MARCADOS,
    COUNT(IAC.CD_ATENDIMENTO)  AS ATENDIDOS,
    COUNT(IAC.CD_ATENDIMENTO) / COUNT(IAC.NM_PACIENTE) * 100 AS PERCENTAGEM_ATENDIDOS

FROM AGENDA_CENTRAL AC
    INNER JOIN IT_AGENDA_CENTRAL   IAC   ON AC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL      = IAC.CD_AGENDA_CENTRAL
    INNER JOIN UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO UA    ON UA.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO = AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO
    INNER JOIN MULTI_EMPRESAS      ME    ON ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA       = AC.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA
WHERE IAC.NM_PACIENTE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY AC.CD_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    UA.DS_UNIDADE_ATENDIMENTO,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA,
    AC.DT_AGENDA
```

Comment: Não rolou, esse convert float funciona para oracle? Dá Erro Ora936 Expressão não encontrada, achei que era só um ')' que estava faltando para fechar a expressão, mas não.

Comment: Tem razão. Veja a edição. Se retirar o CONVERT deve obter o resultado pretendido.

Comment: Foi exatamente o que fiz e funcionou. Obrigado!